# WooCommerce restrict product download by country or region

Tags: php, wordpress, download, woocommerce, restriction

Is there a way/plugin in Wordpress WooCommerce to restrict a certain product from being DOWNLOADED in a certain region. Remember this is not suppose to be site wide, but on a product to product basis.

What I imagine is that on checkout if a product has download  restrictions enabled a function pulls the current user's location (country) and compares it against an array of permitted countries for that product. If there is a match the check in proceeds if not, it returns a message informing the user that the product they requested is not available for download in their country.  THE QUESTION IS, DOES SUCH A PLUGIN, FEATURE, FUNCTION or SNIPPET exist, if so where?

**UPDATE:** Seeing that there was no answer I have gone ahead and started creating something on my own. I have no previous PHP experience so please help me make this code concise. You can try it. IS THIS CORRECT?

**UPDATE (SOLUTION):** Woocommerce now has a built in functionality that checks user location and stores it for the shop owner to use in custom functions, go wild with it :)

The following code goes into your theme's functions.php file. It will add a "Region Settings" panel to your product page's add/edit page under the "General Tab". It has two options, "restriction type:" which can be set to "Allow" or "Deny" and the "Regions: " option where you specify the countries that will be affected. If a product's region settings  are not set, it will allow everyone to access it.

```
/**
 *  Mazwi WooCommerce Region Control BETA 
 * ------------------------------------
 *
 *  
 * 
 * Execute code if the user's country (set for each product) is allowed
 *
 * Author: Taf Makura
 * Thanks to Remi Corson's Tutorial 
 */


// Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

// Display Fields
function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';

  ?>

    <?php
        // Select
            woocommerce_wp_select( 
            array( 
                'id'      => '_restriction-type', 
                'label'   => __( 'Restriction type', 'woocommerce' ), 
                'options' => array(
                'allow'   => __( 'Allow', 'woocommerce' ),
                'deny'   => __( 'Deny', 'woocommerce' ),
        )
    )
);

        // Create Textarea
            woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
            array( 
                'id'          => '_regions', 
                'label'       => __( 'Regions', 'woocommerce' ), 
                'placeholder' => '', 
                'desc_tip'    => 'true',
                'description' => __( 'Please enter two letter country codes. Each country code should be followed by a coma Example: ZW, AU, ZA, US ', 'woocommerce' ) 
        )
    );

  echo '</div>';
}


function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

        // Select
            $woocommerce_select = $_POST['_restriction-type'];
            if( !empty( $woocommerce_select ) )
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_restriction-type', esc_attr( $woocommerce_select ) );


        // Textarea
            $woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_regions'];
            if( !empty( $woocommerce_textarea ) )
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regions', esc_html( $woocommerce_textarea ) );

 }
```

The following code goes into the template .php file where the conditional execution is suppose to happen. I can imagine if you place the add to cart loop (add to cart button) here it will allow you to control which products can be bought in certain countries. On a product by product basis.

```
<?php global $woocommerce; 

        // Get restriction type (deny or allow) for current product
        $restriction_type = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_restriction-type', true );

        // Get region(s) the above restriction type is applied to 
        $regions = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_regions', true );

        // Turns this string into an array. 
        $regions_array = (explode(',', str_replace('/\s+/','', $regions)));

        // Get users current IP location from WooCommerce 
        $base_country = (..... YOU NEED TO GET THE USER LOCATION ISO COUNTRY CODE ......)

        // If user's current IP location is either allowed, is not denied or is not set in the region settings = success
        if( $restriction_type == 'allow' && in_array($base_country , $regions_array) || $restriction_type == 'deny' && !in_array($base_country , $regions_array) || $restriction_type == '' || $regions == '' ) {

                if ($restriction_type == '' || $regions == '') {

                    //  Code to execute on success if a product is not set (NOTE: It will not be restricted)

                    echo('This product\'s region control has not been set, you can set it in WP Admin');
                }

                // Code to execute on success if a products region settings are set to allow access

                echo('YOU ARE IN'); 

        } else {

                // Code to execute when region is restricted

                echo(' you are restricted,');
        }

?>
```

Comment: You answered your question yourself.

Comment: My question is does such a thing, plugin, function or snippet exist and where can I get it?

Comment: Taf (OP), did you ever continue development on this? I am looking for similar functionality, and wondered where you go to with your solution.

Comment: I did manage to create a custom plugin, that checks location and removes add to cart to button when a product is restricted, The admin part of the plugin uses the first snippet of code in my question (UNCHANGED) what's different is the second part, the logic that retrieves the user location and removes add to cart button if the conditions are not met using Woocommerce filters and actions.

Comment: @inspiredlife I have just edited the second code snippet so that it works the way it works in my plugin, you can do the rest, The IMPORTANT thing is that the $base_country in the code above should be the user's 2 letter ISO Country Code you need to get it on your own, using the user's IP Address, Woocommerce now has a built in function to handle this.

Comment: @inspiredlife contact me if you want custom dev

Comment: @TafMak : Thanks for getting back to me on this. I'll have a play with the code you've provided. Cheers... Jonathan

Comment: Please do share improvements or tweaks

Comment: @TafMak: Wow. Looks like I got waylaid on this! I see a year has passed. I was again looking for a solution to this requirement, and found your post, and then I see my comments here! I think for that project (a year ago) some other solution was implemented. Now I have another project requiring the same functionality of geo-restricted products. Does your code (above) still stand as viable, or has it evolved in the past year? Thanks.

Comment: Still worked the last time i checked, only difference i sthat Woocommerce now has GEO coding built in, which makes it much simpler to implement

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you saw/tried this, but according to http://docs.woothemes.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/ you can do what you are asking for.

> To configure your shop go to WooCommerce > Settings. Then browse through the content below to get more information on the WooCommerce Options.
>
> Allowed Countries
>
> Here you can select whether you want to sell/ship to too countries, or
> a select few – useful if only trading within your own country for
> instance. Customers outside your allowed countries will not be able to
> checkout.
>
> Specific Countries
>
> Define the countries you’re willing to sell/ship to. You must set the
> “Allowed Countries” option to "Specific Countries".

Comment: I am aware of this, but 

1) this is a site wide setting, it will affect all products. 
2) WooCommerce has no Geocoding so it relies on information the user provides to determine location. This setting relies on the user's billing address. 

What the above plugin should achieve is:

1) Use Geocoding to determine the user location.
2) Allow site admin to set allowed countries for each product, not the entire site.

Comment: 3) Disable add to cart button or any other template feature when the product the user wants to buy is restricted from their country (The user CANNOT buy the product) this is ideal for location based  licensed items, like movie downloads.


4) IT WORKS WITH DIGITAL downloads too and does not rely on shipping address.